# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. with webpack

Tags: reactjs

Following this great tutorial -https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack - I am trying to learn React.

The source code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <p> Hello React!</p>;
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Then I am making a bundle via `webpack -d` and the following webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/app');

    var config = {
        entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
        output: {
            path: BUILD_DIR,
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },

        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?/, // Files to be processed - *.js and *.jsx
                include : APP_DIR, // Where to look for *.js and *.jsx
                loader : 'babel' // folder name
            }
        ]
    };

    module.exports = config;
```

The bundle end with this error:

> Module parse failed: C:\DEV\PAT\POC-MERN\client\app\index.jsx
>   Unexpected token (6:15) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type.

```
 class App extends React.Component { 
     render(){ 
         return <p> Hello React!</p>;  <---- This line
     }
 }
```

I believe it's something trivial. I just don't see it. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had to wrape `loader:` in `module` aka

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/, // Files to be processed - *.js and *.jsx
                include: APP_DIR, // Where to look for *.js and *.jsx
                loader: 'babel' // folder name
            }
        ]
    }
```